# Trying to add up the total cost of items in a list from user input

Tags: python

Right now I am trying to make it so that after the user inputs items from the provided list which all have an integer value, the program will then add up the user input and print out the integers in the form of US currency. I tried to have a go at it, but I'm not sure what to do from here. I'm new to coding and StackOverflow so sorry about the bad code and formatting.

```
burgers = "2.5"
salad = "2.5"
soup = "2.5"
pizza = "5.5"
fishnchips = "4.5"
tacos = "3.0"
hotdogs = "2.0"

options = ["burgers", "salad", "soup", "pizza", "fishnchips", "tacos", "hotdogs"]

ask = int(input("What would you like to eat? We have burgers, salad, soup, pizza, fishnchips, tacos, and hot dogs"))

x = options

while x == options:
    print("What else would you like to eat?")
    if x!= options:
        print("Ok your food will arrive soon.")
    else:   
        print("Your food", ask, "totals to", )
```

I am trying to make it so that the user would input any of the listed items from the "options" list and my program will print out the total cost of the items inputted

ex.

The total cost of your food is $5.0

Comment: Are the 7 first lines the prices?

Comment: please share whatever error messages you encountered. also note that *indentation is important* in Python. i am not sure if you pasted the code without indents or your source code lacks it too. either way, fix the indents. [refer to this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) for fixing indents

Comment: Yes, they are. @NavidNaseri

Comment: Please include the example of desired input-output you wish your program to have. It will help people understand your problem clearly.

Comment: I haven't encountered an error so far, the problem is that I don't know how to write the code necessary to perform what I mentioned in my question. And I was wondering if anybody knew how to do this and if so could help me in figuring it out. @kevinnls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your menu options and prices into a dict so that you can associate each menu item with its price.

```
menu = {
    "burgers": 2.5,
    "salad": 2.5,
    "soup": 2.5,
    "pizza": 5.5,
    "fishnchips": 4.5,
    "tacos": 3.0,
    "hotdogs": 2.0,
}

choices = [input("What would you like to eat?  We have " + ', '.join(menu.keys()))]
while True:
    x = input("What else would you like to eat?")
    if x not in menu:
        break
    choices.append(x)

print("Ok your food will arrive soon.")
print("Your food", choices, "totals to", sum(menu[x] for x in choices))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is greatly appreciated as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

To get input from user more than once, you should do it *inside* the loop. And it is better to save the foods and their prices in a dictionary:

```
prices = {'burgers' : 2.5, 'salad' : 2.5, ..., 'hotdogs' : 2}
```

Then get the input **and save the total price in a variable**:

```
print('Menu\n========')
for key, value in prices:
    print(f'{key} : ${value}')
total = 0
while True:
    inp = input('What would you like to eat?')
    try:
        total += prices[inp]
    except:
        break
print(f'Total price : {total}')
```